# Поменять переменную в другом классе

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я в шоке, не получается, весь день бьюсь(

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestScript1 : MonoBehaviour {

    //public TestScript2 ts2;
    public GameObject go;
    public float number1 = 0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        number1++;
    }
}
```

второй скрипт на втором объекте

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestScript2 : MonoBehaviour {

    //вариант 1
    //public TestScript1 ts1;

    //вариант2
    public GameObject go;

    public float number2 = 0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        //вариант1
        //number2 = ts1.number1;

        //вариант2
        number2 = go.GetComponent<TestScript1> ().number1;
        Debug.Log (number2);
    }
}
```

Еще пробовал делать геттеры и сеттеры, результат такой же. Короче, мне нужно, чтобы number2 из второго скрипта принимала значение number1 из первого. И все. Сейчас она всегда принимает значение 0 (при этом в первом скрипте я могу написать `public float number1 = 9000f;`, и все равно number2 будет 0. Еще во втором скрипте могу запихнуть ее в Start() и сделать  `number2 = 9000f` или в самом начале `public float number2 = 9000f`, и во всех этих случаях она остается равной 0). Что вообще происходит и что я делаю неправильно? и как правильно?

В сами пребафы я запихнул те, которые нужны (в первый - второй, во второй - первый)

После экспериментов расширяю вопрос.
В `TestScript2` если сделать так, то `number2` становится равной `number1` (той `number1`, которая была при старте)

```
    void Start () {
        //number2 = go.GetComponent<TestScript1> ().number1;
        //number2 = ts1.number1;
    }
```

Работает любая из этих строк. Если их запихнуть в `void Update ()`, то `number2` НЕ изменяется так же, как `number1`, она остается той, которая была при старте.

Получается, `GameObject1` пытается взять значение у префаба `GameObject`, который находится в папке Assets, а не у того, который находится на сцене. Я правильно понял? Если я делаю так, то он берет `number1` у `GameObject`, который находится на сцене, и `number2` меняет свое значение в соответствии с `number1`

```
void Update () {

        var myObject = GameObject.Find("GameObject0");
        number2 = myObject.GetComponent<TestScript1> ().number1;
        Debug.Log (number2);
    }
```

Но это ведь плохое решение? `var myObject = GameObject.Find("GameObject0");` в `void Start ()` не позволяет использовать `myObject` в `void Update ()`. Плюс, если все же использовать это решение, то возникают очень большие проблемы - у меня будет много объектов со скриптом `TestScript1` и столько же объектов с `TestScript2` (последние динамически создаются) и мне нужно, чтобы они попарно брали значения друг у друга.

---

Обновление 2.
Я уже ниего не понимаю((
На сцене создал объект со скриптом (CounterManager):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class CounterManagerScript : MonoBehaviour {

public int maxObjects = 0;
public List<float> counterList; // тут хранятся счетчики

// позиция по Y и "граница" бокс коллайдера по Y
public List<float> objectPositionY;
public List<float> objectBoundsY;

public List<float> stickPositionY;
public List<float> stickBoundsY; // тут нет коллайдера, ее высчитываю по спрайту

public DeliveryStickMoveScript deliveryStick; // сюда засунул объект со скриптом из префаба (палка)
public DeliveryObjectScript deliveryOS; // аналогично, но тут объект ИКС

// тут я присваиваю объектам индексы, так скрипт узнает, куда отправить счетчик
public int counterofObject = -1;
public int counterOfStick = -1;

public void doCounter(){

    for (int i = counterOfStick; i < maxObjects; i++)
        counterList.Add (stickPositionY[i] - stickBoundsY[i]/2 - 
                         objectPositionY[i] + objectBoundsY[i]/2);
}
```

}

Теперь как я присваиваю значения:

```
public class DeliveryStickMoveScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject deliveryObject;

    public int indexOfObject = -1;

    public bool canMove = true;
    public float counter = 0f;
    public float objectBoundY = 0f;

    public bool canToGive = true;

    // суть этого всего - код добавляет значения в List, затем там увеличивает 1 параметр на единицу и присваивает его себе (как бы индекс)
    public void Start () {
        SpriteRenderer sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
        objectBoundY = sr.bounds.size.y;

        onScreen = true; 
        GameObject go = GameObject.Find ("CounterManager");
        go.GetComponent<CounterManagerScript> ().stickPositionY.Add (gameObject.transform.position.y);
        go.GetComponent<CounterManagerScript> ().stickBoundsY.Add (objectBoundY);
        go.GetComponent<CounterManagerScript> ().counterOfStick++;
        go.GetComponent<CounterManagerScript> ().maxObjects++;
        go.GetComponent<CounterManagerScript> ().doCounter ();
        indexOfObject = go.GetComponent<CounterManagerScript> ().counterOfStick;
        //if (indexOfObject == go.GetComponent<CounterManagerScript> ().counterOfStick)
            counter = go.GetComponent<CounterManagerScript> ().counterList [indexOfObject];
        //counter = go.GetComponent<CounterManagerScript> ().objectPositionY [indexOfObject];
    }
public void Update () {

        if (canMove) {
            counter -= 1 * Time.deltaTime;
            if (counter >=0)
            gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3 (gameObject.transform.position.x,
                                                     gameObject.transform.position.y - 1 * Time.deltaTime,
                                                     gameObject.transform.position.z);
            else 
                gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3 (gameObject.transform.position.x,
                                                             gameObject.transform.position.y + 1 * Time.deltaTime,
                                                             gameObject.transform.position.z);
        }
    }
}
```

И первый объект (выше был второй):
public class DeliveryObjectScript : MonoBehaviour {

```
public int indexOfObject = -1;

public Transform deliveryStick;
private bool canCreateStick = true;
public bool startCounter = false; // запустить таймер
public float objectBoundY = 0f;
public float counter = 0f;

public bool onScreen = false; // если true, то CounterManager возьмет параметры

// суть этого всего - код добавляет значения в List, затем там увеличивает 1 параметр на единицу и присваивает его себе (как бы индекс)
public void giveParams(){
    GameObject go = GameObject.Find ("CounterManager");
    go.GetComponent<CounterManagerScript> ().objectPositionY.Add (gameObject.transform.position.y);
    go.GetComponent<CounterManagerScript> ().objectBoundsY.Add (objectBoundY);
    go.GetComponent<CounterManagerScript> ().counterofObject++;
    //go.GetComponent<CounterManagerScript> ().doCounter ();
    indexOfObject = go.GetComponent<CounterManagerScript> ().counterofObject;
    //if (indexOfObject == go.GetComponent<CounterManagerScript> ().counterofObject)
        counter = go.GetComponent<CounterManagerScript> ().counterList [indexOfObject];
    //counter = go.GetComponent<CounterManagerScript> ().stickPositionY [indexOfObject];
    onScreen = true;
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    SpriteRenderer sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
    objectBoundY = sr.bounds.size.y;
}


// Update is called once per frame
public void Update () {

    if (gameObject.GetComponent<ObjectChooserScript> ().canMove == true) {

        gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
        gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = false;

        if (canCreateStick) {
        Instantiate(deliveryStick, new Vector3(gameObject.transform.position.x
                                               ,20
                                               , gameObject.transform.position.z),
                    Quaternion.identity);
        canCreateStick = false;
            if (canCreateStick == false && onScreen == false)
                giveParams();
            startCounter = true;
        }
        if (startCounter)
            counter -= 1 * Time.deltaTime;
        if (counter <=0)

        gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(
            gameObject.transform.position.x,
            gameObject.transform.position.y + 1 * Time.deltaTime,
            gameObject.transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

}

В общем, это дичайшая дичь. Тут он мне выдает `ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.` в `DeliveryObjectScript.giveParams () (at Assets/Scripts/DeliveryObjectScript.cs:25)
DeliveryObjectScript.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/DeliveryObjectScript.cs:63)`. Но самое интересное, что в CounterManager юнити мне показывает, что все параметры принимаются. А, похоже, что `DeliveryObjectScript` "не видит" значения `DeliveryStick`, замена `counter = go.GetComponent<CounterManagerScript> ().counterList [indexOfObject];` на `counter = go.GetComponent<CounterManagerScript> ().stickPositionY [indexOfObject];` выдает тот же результат, а вот наоборот все норм (т.е палка все видит)

Comment: Ошибок (кроме как вызова `GetComponent` в методе `Update` и инкремента числа типа `float` ) - нет. Так что где-то еще что-то ты напутал, не туда скрипт кинул или глюк студии/редактора/компа и т.д. Но в данном случае, если взять эти скрипты, сделать два объекта на 1-ый кинуть 1-ый скрипт и впихнуть туда 2-ой объект, а также взять 2 объект кинуть туда 2-ой скрипт и пихнуть в поле 1-объект - всё работает

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, провел несколько экспериментов и добавил в вопрос новую информацию. У вас эти скрипты точно правильно работают? У меня Unity 5.2.3f1 - просто на всякий случай (установлена вин виста, поменять на семерку нет возможности - бук не мой, следующие версии не поддерживают висту)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, я понял, почему у вас работает - если запихнуть GameObject'ы друг в друга, то все отлично. Но как быть с префабами?

Comment: Скрипты с GO 100% работают.........Префабы это тоже GO)) у тебя именно с префабами не работает?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, ага. Судя по ощущениям, он берет значение не с того объекта, который на сцене, а из самого префаба в папке assets, у которого Update не происходит. Это демо-скрипты, из которых я выкинул все лишнее и оставил только проблему. В настоящем скрипте у меня на сцене нет объектов, я их создаю через Instantiate.  Попробую сделать на сцене менеджер, который будет принимать значения, и уже через него все делать.

Comment: По хорошему можно показать как раз-таки скрипты с инстанциированием и полной логикой что там делаешь. скорее всего при инстанциировании ты ссылку не берешь от этого объекта.......... плюс можно скрин проекта где показать стрелками что куда положил....... а так да... возможно ты что-то не туда положил и в результате данные берутся из префаба не на сцене.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, добавил код

Comment: Без бутылки не разберешься))) почему у тебя в DeliveryObjectScript `public Transform deliveryStick;` вместо `public GameObject deliveryStick;` ?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, в официальных доках по instantiate было именно Transform. У меня она используется только для информации о координатах, больше в этом скрипте эта `deliveryStick` нигде не используется. На всякий случай даже поменял на `GameObject` (мало ли), но ничего не изменилось

Comment: Мне кажется, где-то я с инкрементом что-то напутал, вот он и ссылается на несуществующий индекс, но который раз пересматриваю код и не могу найти, вроде все норм. Самое непонятное - почему палка видит объект. Вроде и там, и там, один и тот же код(почти), но с объектом что-то не то

Comment: Идея этого менеджера в следующем: каждый раз при определённом событии (для объекта это TriggerEnter, он написан в другом скрипте, тут его отображают bool-флаги, для палки - момент её создания) в менеджер отправляются их параметры - позиция и bounds этого объекта и палки, там все они имеют индекс начиная с 0 и так далее, а потом получают счетчик. В скрипте менеджера происходит добавления счётчика в зависимости от параметров, а потом каждый объект и палка забирают счётчик того индекса, который указан в objectIndex объекта и палки.

Comment: Для этого они в менеджере увеличивают counterOfObject (или counterOfStick для палки) на единицу, а затем присваивают своим indexOfObject полученное число. Таким образом каждый счётчик будет правильным для каждого объекта и палки

Answer (score 2):

> получается, GameObject1 пытается взять значение у префаба GameObject, который находится в папке Assets, а не у того, который находится на сцене. Я правильно понял?

Да. Так ты хранишь ссылку на префаб, а не на объект на сцене. Изначально нужно продумать логику нахождения нужного  тебе объекта при инициализации. Из твоего скрипта:

```
    TestScript1 myObject;
    void Update () {
        if(myObject == null)
            myObject = GameObject.Find("GameObject0").GetComponent<TestScript1> ();
        number2 = myObject.number1;
        Debug.Log (number2);
    }
```

Или:

```
  void Start () {
               myObject = GameObject.Find("GameObject0").GetComponent<TestScript1> ();
    }
```

Но не безопасно искать по имени, так как объектов может быть много и у него скорей всего будет окончание (Clone). Нужно реализовать поиск иначе.

Answer (score 0):

Решение не найдено, я просто обошел проблему. Весь код с менеджером оставил как есть, поменял только одну мелочь: у меня палка имеет доступ к объекту, параметры которого (размер и т.д) могут отличаться - она знает о его параметрах. А этот самый объект о параметрах палки не знает, но у этой палки всегда они одни и те же. Так что я просто у `DeliveryObjectScript` удалил все попытки взять параметры папки у менеджера, и теперь она берет их у префаба палки - все довольны, все счастливы. Но сама проблема не решена - если кто сюда заглянет и подскажет, что да как, скажу спасибо. Отдельное спасибо Valera Kvip за подсказку про поиск объектов

Comment: Ну если возможно: Пусть палка создает объект или объект палку, и во время создания  они обмениваются ссылками друг на друга. Или если папка знает об объекте, то нужно в момент, когда она о нем узнает, послать объекту ссылку на палку. Но кстати в данном случае решение почти правильное, только я бы сделал отдельный класс с информацией о префабе и брал все значения оттуда, потому что так ты создаешь объекты с неизменными полями, но память то выделяется. Или можно обозначить их как const.